# I have one power apps (store data in sharepoint) and now, it is ready for go live but what is best practice to roll out

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I want to create three environments: Development, QA, and production for my apps in power apps.
Not sure what is best solution for this.  This app store data in sharepoint lists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have a cool way of handling this. Maybe it works for you as well.

**NOTE:** This method does not seem to work for VERY large Sharepoint lists (over 100k records).

1. Create a `DEV` Sharepoint list and a `DEV` PowerApps environment and begin all of your PowerApps developent against this list.

   - When it is in a good place (all columns added, all the bugs worked out), use a copy of this list to create a `PROD` Sharepoint list.
   - Create a `PROD` PowerApps environment as well; copy your `DEV` PowerApp to the new environment.
   - Repeat for a `QA` list and app if you like
2. Within your app, add a Radio button with Items property set to `["DEV", "QA", "PROD"]`
3. For the PowerApp within the `DEV` env, set the Default property of the radio button to "DEV". Repeat for the other env's respectively.

   - Its important to set this Default property EVERY TIME you push the app into the next environent.
   - Maybe someday PowerApps will expose the Environment as an app property and you can set this programmatically.
4. (Here's the special sauce) For all of your logic where you ClearCollect, Filter, Patch, LookUp, etc. (anywhere you call a Sharepoint datasource), use an IF statement to control which Sharepoint list the app looks at. 
   4a. Set the radio button's `OnSelect` property to `Set(varEnv, rdoEnv.Selected.Value)`
   4b. For all code which use a Sharepoint list write your code with the IF statement. Something like:

```
Filter(
  If(
    varEnv = "DEV", MY_DEV_LIST,
    varEnv = "QA", MY_QA_LIST,
    varEnv = "PROD", MY_PROD_LIST
  ),
  someValue = anotherValue
)
```

**Works like a charm AS LONG AS:**

1. The columns in your lists are exactly the same
2. If you use this with a Form controls DataSource property, you'll need to set it to ONE of the lists when you add/remove fields.

   - After a field is added/removed, you can revert the DataSource property to the If statement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For my point of view, before going to live , test it properly in Development and QA environment.

Still you want ro revert it back , then you can disable the DisableAppViews in the admon center, so your list will open in a normal view not in powerapps .

And take everyday backup of your list means save list as a list template .

These are the option I can suggest to do .